# Simple note-taking extension for Chrome and Firefox

Tags: chrome, offline, note-taking, firefox

I am looking for a simple note-taking extension that fulfils the following criteria:

- Available for Chrome and Firefox
- Provides sticky notes functionality
- Synchronisation across both browsers
- Writable or at least accessible without internet connection
- At best open source

Does anyone know of a simple extension?

The closest in terms of note-taking that I have found is [padlet](http://padlet.com/). However, it does not have an offline mode.

Answer (score 1):

[Draft](http://draftin.com) has recently added offline support, and has [Chrome plugin](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/draft/amlbbbgcijmiooecobhkjblcdkjldmdk?hl=en)

Looks like there's something for [Firefox](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/draft-for-firefox/?src=search) too.

Comment: Thanks but I forgot to mention that I prefer to have sticky notes instead of only text. And with Draft I do not see any option to create these type of notes.

Comment: Ah yes - Draft is not what you want, then.